# Excel VBA #Value! Error

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error, udf

I have the following function that when I run it says #value! error.

I would appreciate any help.

```
Function Bootstrap(S As Object, Z As Object, L As Double)

    Dim j As Integer
    Dim a() As Double
    Dim b() As Double
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim Q() As Double
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim P As Double

    ReDim a(1 To n)
    ReDim b(1 To n)
    ReDim Q(1 To n)

    dt = 1
    sum = 0
    Q(0) = 0

    For j = 1 To n - 1
        S.Cells(j, 1).Value = a(j)
        Z.Cells(j, 2).Value = b(j)
        P = Z(j) * (L * Q(j-1) - (L + dt * a(n) * Q(j))
        sum = sum + P
    Next j

    Bootstrap = sum

End Function
```

Bootstrapping function calculates the following value
In fact I am trying to calculate this  formula 
Q(t,Tn)=(∑(j=1)to(n-1) Z(t,Tj)*[LQ(t,Tj-1)-(L+dt*Sn)*Q(t,Tj)]/[Z(t,Tn)*(L+dt*Sn)]  +(Q(t,Tn-1)*L)/(L+dt*Sn)

Inputs given are[S1 ,S2,….Sn ],[Z(t,T1),Z(t,T2)…..Z(t,Tn)]and and L=0.4

Comment: Please explain step by step the calculation that you are trying to do, because this is very very dark, you can edit your post to include this and help us help you... Because right now, I'm really shooting in the dark!

Comment: @R3uK. I have editted and given the formula for Bootstrapping function. I hope its not dark now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code : entered as =Bootstrap(A1:B1,A2:B2,0.4)
I have corrected the following
- Assigning the ranges to variants
- defining dt as double
- Dim Q() as 0 to n
- using A() and b() in the formula
- the input ranges are rows not columns

```
Function Bootstrap(S As Range, Z As Range, L As Double) As Double
Dim j As Integer
Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Variant
Dim n As Integer
Dim Q() As Double
Dim sum As Double
Dim P As Double
Dim dt As Double

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(S.Columns.Count, Z.Columns.Count)
a = S.Value
b = Z.Value
dt = 1
sum = 0
ReDim Q(0 To n)
Q(0) = 0

For j = 1 To n - 1
    P = b(1, j) * (L * Q(j - 1)) - (L + dt * a(1, j) * Q(j - 1))
    sum = sum + P
    Q(j) = sum
Next j

Bootstrap = sum
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. This gives some output values. It seems to be correct. I am checking. But what if Inputs are in Columns not Rows ? Then simply changing the Application .WorkshhetFunction.Max(S.Rows.Count,Z.Rows.Count) ?

Comment: Then use Rows.Count instead of Columns.Count and reverse the indices in references to a() and b()

Answer (score 2):

Take the habit to format and increment your code, especially before posting it!

---

1. You need to type the output of the function (on the line of the function name)
2. A parenthesis is missing from the line `P = Z(j) * (L*Q(j-1)-(L+ dt * a(n) * Q(j))`
3. `n` is empty (and so are `a`, `b` and `Q`) when you try to redim your arrays, so you need to define them!
4. `Z(j)` will also give you an error, because it is a Range, you need `Z.Cells(i,j)`

Try this :

```
Function Bootstrap(S As Range, Z As Range, L As Double) As Double
Dim j As Integer
Dim a() As Double
Dim b() As Double
Dim n As Integer
Dim Q() As Double
Dim sum As Double
Dim P As Double

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(S.Columns.count, Z.Columns.count)
a = S.Value
b = Z.Value
dt = 1
sum = 0
ReDim Q(1 To n)
Q(0) = 0
'Q(1) = "??"


For j = 1 To n - 1
    P = b(1, j) * (L * Q(j - 1)) - (L + dt * a(1, j) * Q(j - 1))
    sum = sum + P
    Q(j) = sum
Next j

Bootstrap = sum
End Function
```

Comment: I again tried running the code by putting n=2 ,but it shows the same #value! error.

Comment: In the Excel Spreadhseet output cell D1, I type =Bootstrap(A1:A2,B1:B2,0.4) ,which generates the #value! error.

Comment: The issue is your calculation and the fact that you use empty variables (here, `a`, `b`, `Q` are empty so you just erase the content of the cells that you select and calculate `P` with empty variables, so in fact the calcul is `P = 0 - L = - L`. See also point 4

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do? Or correct your algorithm for the calcul in the loop, because the reel problem is here! ;)

Comment: I have replaced Z(j) by Z.Cells(j,2).Value but no effect and my input is Z column matrix which I have stored the the values in Z to b matrix and similarly S to a() . So, a & b should NOT be empty .The inital value of Q is 0 i.e. Q(0) but for values say j= 2 ,Q(2) will be required ,which is NOT there. I am correcting the the calculation part of Q(j) and checking.

Comment: Infact I am Bootstrapping the value Q for different time horizons where Q(1) will be derived from Q(0) ..Q(2) to be derived from Q(1)..Q(3) from Q2)....Q(n) from Q(n-1)using the summation formula from j = 1 to n-1 which contains input from the colum matrix S, Z and the value of  L... Are you getting what I am trying to do ?

Comment: And the Bootstrapping formula is  Q(n)= Summation of (Z(j)*(L+S(j+1))/Z(j-1)*(L*dt* S(j)) from j = 1 to n-1

Comment: @PankajMani : Honestly, not really... Try the edit, I think it is close from what you are trying to do, except for Q which I don't get... BTW I'm not sure bootstrap is a verb, and I haven't the faintest clue of what you mean by it (ok the formula is a start...)!

Comment: I can share the complete formula file with you .Bootstrap is basically a function which calculates the term structure of Q for different time horizon subsequently .  I think we are close but somewhere something is missing ,which shows the  value error.

Comment: Clearly, it is the Q part that is the problem... Edit your post to include formulas and explanations step by step, I'll finish this once I can get a grip of what your are trying to do mathematically speaking!

Comment: Please see the answer by Charles. It seems correct. By the way what do you mean by formatting as you suggested to me before posting?

Comment: I'm a bit astonished as his answer is the same as mine except for the dimensioning of `dt` that I forgot, but anyway... And by formating, I mean deleting useless empty rows, using horizontal increments to help readability and things like this! ;)

Comment: Ok. yes..very little difference. Thanks.